# Unable to stop execution of setTimeout with clearTimeout function

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, settimeout, cleartimeout

I am using a Ajax request to continue watch in database.
If something returns from DB then Execution must stop.
If something returns from DB then I am using clearTimeout to stop the execution of setTimeout loop, but its not working.
Here is the code :

```
var timeRunner;
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'checkInDb.php',
        data: {
            tName: tName
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            mStudent = obj.student;
            mTeacher = obj.teacher;
            mTime = obj.time;
            console.log(mStudent, mTeacher, mTime);

            if (mStudent != '') {

                clearTimeout(timeRunner);

            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            timeRunner = setTimeout(worker, 2000);
        }
    });
})();
```

Here if something is coming in `mStudent` then i want to stop execution but is not working.

Comment: The `complete()` callback is invoked *after* `success()`.

Comment: So can i define complete before success?

Comment: It doesn't matter what order you declare them in. Just move the logic into the `success()` callback: if the `mStudent` value *is* empty, then start the timer. The code as written cannot possibly work.

Comment: Yes, i try that now.

Comment: Sorry again, but now its returning `Unexpected token r in JSON at position 4`

Comment: Well what exactly does the JSON look like? That error is coming from `JSON.parse()` so you'll have to look at the actual content to know why you're getting an error.

Comment: If something there in DB, then it works and stop execution but if something not there then null come in json then this error came

Comment: That sounds like a server-side problem. The server has to ensure that valid JSON is returned in all cases.

Comment: I figured it out, when i set `dataType: 'html'` then all things works fine.